# http-server won't work after repeated reinstallations

Tags: node.js, npm

Previously the http-server command from cmd worked but suddenly it just stopped getting recognized. Back when it was working the browser couldn't connect to `localhost:8000`.

I have tried reinstalling the module thrice. I've added the http-server directory to PATH manually and cmd still doesn't recognize it.

```
C:\Users\ryuji>npm install -g http-server
C:\Users\ryuji\AppData\Roaming\npm\hs -> C:\Users\ryuji\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\http-server\bin\http-server
C:\Users\ryuji\AppData\Roaming\npm\http-server -> C:\Users\ryuji\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\http-server\bin\http-server
+ http-server@0.11.1
added 26 packages from 28 contributors in 2.582s

C:\Users\ryuji>http-server
'http-server' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

to run a localhost server with node

Comment: did you add `http-server\bin` or just `http-server` in PATH?

Comment: After configure the `PATH`, have you closed and re-opened your cmd window?

Answer (score 0):

http-server needs to be installed globally with `npm install -g http-server`